# Spring AOP ignore JPA's repository method annotated

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-aop, spring-data-rest

I've a Spring Boot 2.3 project using Spring Data REST, Spring JPA, Hibernate.

I've a Aspect like this that apply an Hibernate filters to all my queries:

```
@Aspect
@Order(1)
@Component
@Log4j2
public class PortalSecurityAspect {

    @Pointcut("!@annotation(com.server.aop.ExcludePortalSecurityCheck) && execution(public * javax.persistence.EntityManager+.*Query(..))")
    private void createQuery() {
    }

    @Around(value = "createQuery() && target(entityManager)")
    public Object applyFilter(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, Object entityManager) throws Throwable {
        try {
            if (SecurityUtils.getLoggedRoles().contains(Role.ROLE_CUSTOMER)) {
                if (SecurityUtils.getLoggedId() != null) {
                    ((EntityManager) entityManager).unwrap(Session.class).enableFilter("customerFilter").setParameter("contactId", SecurityUtils.getLoggedId());
                    log.trace(">>>>Enabling filter customer {}", SecurityUtils.getLoggedUser().getSid());
                } else {
                    ((EntityManager) entityManager).unwrap(Session.class).enableFilter("customerFilter").setParameter("contactId", -1l);
                    log.warn("Logged ID is null. Customer filter cannot be applied");
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.warn("Unable to enable filter");
        }
        return pjp.proceed();
    }

}
```

I've some JPA repositories like this:

```
@Transactional
@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
public interface DocumentRepository extends JpaRepository<Document, Long>, DocumentCustomRepository<Document, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Document> {


    @ExcludePortalSecurityCheck
    @Cacheable(cacheNames = "documents#chartpopulartimes")
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    @Query("SELECT etc etc etc etc")
    List<Object[]> chartPopularTimes(@Param("from") Instant from, @Param("until") Instant until, @Nullable @Param("storeId") Long storeId);
```

I'd like the hibernate filter is note added to some special methods annotated with my custom annotation `@ExcludePortalSecurityCheck`.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface ExcludePortalSecurityCheck {
}
```

As you see in the Aspect Pointcut I defined a condition  `!@annotation(com.server.aop.ExcludePortalSecurityCheck)` set in AND with the other. Hovewer even if I invoke that method the `PortalSecurityAspect` apply the filter any time. Probably the pointcut is applied to a Spring class method that doesn't have that annotation. Do you have some suggestion about it?

Comment: In Java annotations on interface methods are not inherited by implementing methods. I don't know if Spring does some extra magic there, but by normal JVM means (e.g. compilation via javac) the annotation will not be present on the implementing method. Does it work if you put the annotation on the concrete implementing method?

Comment: @kriegaex Thanks for the clarification. Actually there isn't any concrete implementation of the repository method. I take advantage of Query annotation. Do you think using a Pointcut using the method's name could work? Any hint? Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just try?  But yes, that would help because the name will be the same in all implementing components, it does not vanish like the annotation on the interface method.

Comment: Hi @drenda were you able to solve this?